# Converting a list of options to a JavaScript arrary in C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to get a JSON string that looks like the following:

```
{"1":[{"value":"1", "text":"Basketball"}, {"value":"2", "text":"Tennis"}, {"value":"3", "text":"Football"}],"3":[{"value":"4", "text":"futbol"}]}
```

The C# code responsible for building this looks like the following:

```
var sportsEntries = new Dictionary<byte, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>();
foreach (var department in Departments)
{
  var deptOptions = SportList
    .Where(x => x.DeptId == department.DeptId)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.SportId, x => x.SportNameName).ToList();
  sportsEntries .Add(department.DeptId, deptOptions);
}
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sportsEntries);
```

Unfortunately, this approach generates the wrong JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{"1":[{"Key":1,"Value":"Basketball"},{"Key":2,"Value":"Tennis"},{"Key":3,"Value":"Football"}],"3":[{"Key":4, "Value":"Futbol"}]}
```

I feel like I'm so close. Yet, I'm not sure how to update my C# code to make the resulting JSON look like the format I need. How do I update the C# to output the correct JSON?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use a `SelectListItem` instead of `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, or you could just create a small Class using your properties ("value", "text"), or, better yet, just use an object.

Comment: @AndreiV Is there a way to do it in the code I've written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
var sportsEntries = new Dictionary<byte, List<object>();
foreach (var department in Departments)
{
   var deptOptions = SportList
     .Where(x => x.DeptId == department.DeptId)
     .Select(x => new { value = x.SportId, text = x.SportNameName}).ToList();
   sportsEntries .Add(department.DeptId, deptOptions);
}
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sportsEntries);
```

This solution replaces the initial `KeyValuePair<int, string>` with `object` and creates a list of anonymous objects, having the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SoTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department
            {
                DeptId = 1
            }
        };
        var sportList = new List<Sport>
        {
            new Sport
            {
                DeptId = 1,
                SportId = 1,
                SportName = "Basketball"
            },
            new Sport
            {
                DeptId = 1,
                SportId = 2,
                SportName = "Tennis"
            }
        };

        var sportsEntries = new Dictionary<byte, List<Kvp>>();

        foreach (var department in departments)
        {
            var deptOptions = sportList
                .Where(x => x.DeptId == department.DeptId)
                .Select(x => new Kvp { Value = x.SportId, Text = x.SportName }).ToList();
            sportsEntries.Add(department.DeptId, deptOptions);
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sportsEntries);

        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(json);
        Debug.Print(json);
    }
}

public class Department
{
    public byte DeptId { get; set; }
}

public class Sport
{
    public byte DeptId { get; set; }
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Kvp
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```